# how to find the most repeated values in sql

Tags: php, sql, database

In my table i have something like

```
id    file_id
1       1
1       2
1       4
2       1
2       4
2       6
```

I need to find the most frequent file_id regardless of the id, so for example i need the output something like

```
file_id    count
1            2
4            2
..           ..
```

Im using php and phpmyadmin

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle DB?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: sql, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
select 
  file_id, 
  count(*) as count
from table_name
group by file_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select file_id, count(*) as count
from  files
group by file_id
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT file_id, count(id) 
FROM f 
GROUP BY file_id 
ORDER BY count(file_id) DESC;

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you can do:

```
select f.file_id, cnt
from (select file_id, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by file_id, id
     ) f
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple SQL in your case:

```
select file_id, count(id)
from ur_table
group by file_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Using aggregate function

```
SELECT count(id) AS count FROM table GROUP BY file_id
```

Comment: That won't work and it won't help. He wanted to group by file_id

Comment: Thanks, it was typo

Comment: And `coun` does not exist either